# Including process output in tar file

Tags: tar, fifo

I have a simple bash script to generate a compressed tar file and upload it to an external server for backup purposes.  In addition to files on the server, I'd like to include dumps of a few mysql databases.

Due to disk space constraints, I can no longer afford to pre-generate the database dumps to a file on disk before generating the tar archive.  What I'd like to do is somehow stream the dumps directly to tar.

My first attempt was to try creating a named pipe and having tar read that.  For each database to dump, generate a pipe to a mysqldump process:

```
mkfifo $DB.sql
mysqldump --result-file=$DB.sql $DB &
echo $DB.sql >>$FILELIST
```

After generating a list of all files to backup:

```
tar c -P --files-from=$FILELIST | gzip | curl ...
```

I've discovered that this does not work as I expected.  tar simply generates a pipe entry in the archive rather than reading the contents of the pipe.

I could not find any switches to tar to change the behaviour.  Is there some way to get tar to read the pipe as if it were a file, or is there some other utility that would be capable of handling this type of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking that you could use a [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem or something but then I realized that there is a problem with this in principle and that it is impossible to do.

You need `tar`'s output to be streamed out to a remote system with `curl`, which means that `tar` must be able to write its output fully sequentially. But [the `tar` file format](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) requires that each member of the archive be preceeded with a header that describes it, and that header contains among other things the size of the member. But if the contents of the member file are themselves coming from a pipe then it will be impossible for `tar` to know in advance what the size will be and therefore impossible to write the header and proceed to the file data.

Comment: If there's enough space for one dump at a time, that would be possible, maybe with [scriptfs](https://code.google.com/p/scriptfs/) (not sure whether it supports reporting the size in advance).

Comment: Yes, if there's enough space for one dump then something can be arranged somehow. I shouldn't say "impossible" so categorically.

Comment: I gave scriptfs a couple test runs.  It reports the file's size as that of the script.  tar did correctly get the output of the script, but truncated it at the reported script size.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure that's what you want. To read from a pipe means to read from standard input. This is done using `tar xf -` (or `tar xzf -` for compressed streams), where the `-` indicates standard input. Similarly to write to standard output: `tar cf -` (or `tar czf -`).